# What is the best practice to show articles ordered by an "on the fly score calculation" with pagination

Tags: mysql, arrays, sorting, laravel, pagination

I have to paginate and display a large count of articles ordered by "score", this score is not saved anywhere but calculated on the page load.

The score of articles depends on a lot of things like hits, shares, likes, favorites, and what I mean is that I can't put the logic in an SQL query.

So, what i did is : get full data -> calculate score for all data -> order by top score -> display as array chunks (with Laravel custom paginator)

---

```
$Articles =  DB::table('articles')->get();

//for test purpose here i can run a for-loop and print its values

foreach ($Articles as $Article) {
    echo "Article id : ".$Article->id";
    //here i cant print $Article->score
}

$Articles = $this->likesScoreFunction1($Articles);
$Articles = $this->scorefunction2($Articles);
$Articles = $this->scorefunction3($Articles);
```

What I am doing in `scoreFunctions` is adding an extra array value with name "score" and next function update with latest score and so on. I mean after these functions for testing I can run a `for` loop like below :

```
foreach ($Article as $Article) {
    echo "Article id : ".$Article->id." score is ".$Article->score."\n";
}

usort($Articles, function($a, $b) {
   return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
});
```

Finally I got articles sorted by score here at `$Articles;`

Then I pass first array chunks to view.

I know this is not a good method because I load all articles' values in memory. Can anyone please recommend any better method for this?

> The score can be different at different minutes or seconds..

One possibility is to run a cron each minute and update the score fields. It's not practical because this processes all articles from all organization in the system.

My client doesn't want to go with the above method because when any user posts an article it has the highest score and it should come to top. Here we won't see the new article on top until the cron completes it's job.

Comment: I would store the score of each article in the database and try to update it each time accordingly to your business rules. I don't see the point to calculate this value on page load: let's assume that the score doesn't change between my requests, you have to perform that computation every time, even if the current value is equals to the previous. Moreover if your function depends on additional database queries you could add unnecessary delay to your response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a complex ranking algorithm a few weeks ago and tried various approaches you described.

**Pure SQL** was difficult to debug and maintain and slow to execute. The database must select all articles, join in all relevant votes/scores/etc, sort the entire collection then return the paginated result. In some cases it can't use indexes for this. The database cache was being filled with (to me) irrelevant records.

A front-end cache was applied to the pure SQL version. We couldn't find a comfortable caching age - either ranks were outdated or too many requests were missing the cache.

**SQL and PHP** for realtime calculations wasn't attempted. It could only have been slower than the pure SQL method, I think.

To get timely results we had to **store the calculated rank** values ahead of time. There are a few ways to achieve it, as you're already exploring;

- Re-calculate the entire catalog as a `cron` job - as you know is too slow and dance-y
- *Event listeners* re-calculate the ranks of specific articles when an *event* takes place (a vote, social share, etc) - we used this to good effect, but too many events were causing too many simultaneous calculations in our scenario
- An event *queue* keeps track of all recent events. A process or `cron` job re-calculates the ranks of articles which have the most activity currently in the queue, thereby wiping out the most possible queued jobs and using CPU cycles for most effect.

The event queue worked for us so I stopped looking for other solutions. We did add a microcache with Varnish of 1-3 seconds to relieve the database from the traffic burden to ensure a good balance between realtime work and rank calculations.

SQL is still good with time-based calculations, I wouldn't look to fire regular events on articles to degrade ranks over time, for example. If ranks are a combination of events and times I would store pre-calculated event-based ranks, the posted time, and have the SQL query calculate a combination.

When our ranks got that complicated we used a separate table purely for ranks (fixed-width data columns, clever indexing) with a one-to-one relationship to articles. Or a many-to-one relationship if users can choose how to rank them. This way the database doesn't need to load all article data and trawl through inefficient indexes each time. Simply join in article data after the rank pagination.

If you're using Doctrine watch out for greedy hydration.

HTH!